# How to achieve smooth (hw accelerated) transitions in the Android browser?

Tags: css, android, webkit, transform, hardware-acceleration

the title is self-explaining. On iPhone, Mobile Safari is WebKit based and supports hardware-accelerated -webkit-transform CSS properties. To be specific, I use the translate3d() transform.

What alternative is there for the Android browser? I need it to work on Android 1.5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android browser is webkit based as well so your animations should work as desired.

Take a look at an article I read recently.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-androidiphone1/

Comment: I tried to transform an element on a separate page and it does work on the Android 2.2 but not on 1.5.

Comment: The Android 1.5 browser has proven to be quite crap actually, even animated gifs don't work which is a shame.

Comment: You might need to use javascrpit/jquery to achieve the desired animation, but I'm not sure it'll be hardware accelerated.

Comment: Drawing on Android is not hw accelerated anywhere. The reason given for this is that lower end/older devices didn't support it. So hopefully it will come in Android 3.0 :)

Comment: To add to that - forcing transitions to be 3D on Android makes them MUCH slower than 2D; the glimmer of good news is that 2D transforms seem faster on the Android than iPhone/iPad...

Comment: @OskarAustegard Isn't that because 3D transforms are HW acceleratered on iOS while 2D transforms are not?  That could be new information though, considering you posted this 18months ago.  Anyone else have any updated information on this topic?

Comment: for reference: search this article for '2D':
http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/21/play-with-hardware-accelerated-css/

Comment: @colindo: yes, my comment was in reference to that - many will naively use 3D on all webkit browsers thinking it will result in HW acceleration, while in reality it is/was? an iOS thing only...